# .csv file is only readable

Tags: machine-learning

I am sorry if this question might not belong here. I did not know where to post it. I am using JupyterLab and working in a jupyter notebook and using python. I needed to upload an updated .csv file. While I can show the content of the updated file in the notebook, I can not create data frames out of it as it was the case with the previous file. More precisely, when I try to extract two columns satisfying a condition, I get as result only the names of the columns. When I save the new data frame into a .csv file,the file is then up to the names of the two columns empty. I eventually thought to provide executable permissions regarding the initial .csv file, but it did not change anything. When I read the former .csv file, I have not the problem of doing the same operations. It seems as if the updated .csv file is only readable. As proof of principle, I checked the same thing in google colab. There was no difference. I am using Ubuntu 20.04. and JupyterLab via anaconda.
Here is the code:

```
`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
sfari_df = pd.read_csv('data/SFARI-Gene.csv')
sfari_df.head()
sfari_df_new_score2 = sfari_df[sfari_df["gene-score"] ==   2.0][["gene-symbol", "ensembl-id"]]
sfari_df_new_score2.to_csv('sfari_df_new_score2.csv', index = False)
sfari_df_new_score2.head()`
```

The output is:
`gene-symbol    ensembl-id` with no data below the columns. In case I open the .csv file by only clicking at it, I only see two column names with no entries below each of the columns.

Can somebody tell me why this happens, i.e. why I can not manipulate the updated .csv file ?
Many thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked that your filtering actually returns any rows, i.e. are there actually rows in your dataset with a value of 2 in the `gene-score` column? Also make sure that the data types of the columns are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Thanks. The initial dataset I was using and the updated one are the same in regard to the structure. The same code should function on both of them. I do not see any reason for not doing so. I also changed the `gene-score` value from float into integer but it did not change anything.

Comment: Have you actually checked this is the case though? Try adding a `print(sfari_df_new_score2.shape)` to make sure that you actually have rows of data before trying to export them to a csv file.

Comment: I did that before saving the new data frame into a .csv file. The answer is `(0, 2)`. This is really very strange. I can read a large file that contains some 1000 rows but I can not modify it. Can a .csv file be protected from any modification ?

Comment: Based on the shape that gets returned it seems that the filtering does not match any rows, therefore the issue is not related to exporting the data. Would it be possible to share (part of) the data? If not, you will need to have another look at the filter you are applying since it does not give back what you expect.

Comment: The data is downloadable from the site https://gene.sfari.org/database/human-gene/     If you scroll down just little bit you will find it an the right side. Otherwise I can hang a picture on the post. Showing a snippet of data is impossible given its structure.

Comment: Just checked the data and mentioned earlier the data type of the `gene-score` column does not match with the value you are comparing, i.e. the column is of type object whereas you are comparing to an integer or float, which therefore will never give a match. Change your filter expression to look for the string `"2"` and you will get all rows where the `gene-score` has a value of 2.

Comment: Many thanks. But this is not the way it looked like previously. I am showing that on the post. I posted the two versions how they look like when called as a string and as integers. Is there a way to change it to the integer or float type ? Also it is strange that I used the previous release of the same data set and had not that problem.

Comment: By the way, also the index is different between the two versions.

Comment: The change (both the issue you are now getting as well as the change in index) is likely caused by the fact that new data has been added. As a result there now is a gene with `gene-type` `"S"`, which cannot be parsed as a number and as a result the whole `gene-type` column is now of type object. Because new rows are added the resulting indices of your filter will also slightly differ.

Comment: I agree as far as the index is concerned and that the label ''S'' is introduced in the `gene-score` column. So, there is no way in changing the type of the data aiming at making it look like previously?

Comment: You can change the data types of a column by using [`pandas.DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) or using the `dtype` argument of `pandas.read_csv` when reading in the data, however, you cannot convert text to a number without losing data.